# Google Script Editor : Apply to all sheets except 3 specific sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently this code is only applied to the sheet called "Name" I wanted applied to all except for 3 sheets (Template,Summary and Count)

Summary of code: If the value in cell A5 (soon will change to a cell range) is greater than or equal to 15 then send an email.

```
function EqualValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name");
  var value = sheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
  if(value >= "15") sendEmail(value)

};


function sendEmail(value){
  var recipient="Tester@test.com";
  var subject=" test subject " +value;
  var body="The Value is "+value;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
};
```

I am not sure how is best to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude some Google sheet tabs and only include others, you can put the sheet tab names to exclude into an array.

Get all the sheet tabs in the spreadsheet, and loop through them, checking each name.  If the name of the sheet tab being checked is in a list of sheet tab names to exclude, then don't do anything.

```
function EqualValue() {
  var allSheetTabs,i,L,thisSheet,thisSheetName,sheetsToExclude,value;

  sheetsToExclude = ['Template','Summary','Count'];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  allSheetTabs = ss.getSheets();

  L = allSheetTabs.length;

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {
    thisSheet = allSheetTabs[i];
    thisSheetName = thisSheet.getName();

    //continue to loop if this sheet is one to exclude
    if (sheetsToExclude.indexOf(thisSheetName) !== -1) {continue;}

    value = thisSheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
    if(value >= "15") sendEmail(value)
  }
```

Comment: Nice. Made a slight edit as you called sheet rather than thisSheet for the .getRange

Comment: any reason why .getRange isn't working if i put A5:A100?

Comment: I'd use the syntax of `getRange(5,1,95,1).getValues()`  The parameters are: `getRange(start_Row, start_column, number_of_rows, number_of_columns)`  And you need to use `getValues()`  note the letter "s" on the end, for multiple rows.  And you'll also need to change the test to `if (value[0][0] >= "15") sendEmail(value)`

Comment: Thanks! Why is it necessary to change  `if (value[0][0] >= "15") sendEmail(value)` just for knowledge? @SandyGood

Comment: The `getValues()` method returns a 2 Dimensional array.  There is an outer container of elements, and an inner container of elements.  In other words, there is an outer array, and multiple inner arrays.  Each inner array represents a row.  Each element in an inner array represents an individual cell value in a column.  In order to get a value out of an array, you need to refer to the index placement of the element.  Arrays are zero indexed, meaning that the first element is given an index of zero.  So the third row in the outer array is index 2.  "0,1,2"  The 2 is in the third place.